# How to SUM all cells in a column that are equal zero in the same row but previous column? (Google Sheets)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

This is my first question on StackOverflow.

I am trying to SUM all cells in a column that are equal to zero in the previous column in Google Sheets.

[image: Example Sheet in Google Sheets]

I can easily `SUM` each column or the differences between them. However, I also need to `SUM` non-zero cells that are zero in the previous column.

For example:
I need to `SUM` cells `C4` and `C16` as `B4` and `B16` are 0, but `C4` and `C16` are not. I need to come up with a formula that will do this for every column starting with `Column B`.

The result of this formula for `Column B = 0` and `Column C = 1300` that I would be able to monitor.

Ideally, I also need to `SUM` cells that are greater (or less) than the cell in the same row but the previous column.

The result for `Column D = 250` (D4-C4+D16-C16) but `Column E = -250`.

I have been struggling with this for days now – I've tried Indexing, matching, but never cracked any of these problems.

Here's an editable Google Sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rA1VMfjsIajVrwoYN7p_uovzze9GZQbsYnqz200LkrI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Whoever solves these, I'd be more than happy to buy you a cup of coffee!

Comment: i can help.  Can you put the "expected" values where you'd like to see them?

Comment: @MattKing Hey Matt, I added supplemental information and expected values in the shared Google Sheet. Logging off for today, but please let me know if there's anything else I can do to clarify my struggle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a new tab called MK_Data and MK_Summary.  I wanted a "clean dataset" so i could design a solution that anticipated future data.  On MK_Summary, you'll find some formulas dragged down next to the month-year combos.  One is for the Δ $ and looks like this:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(FILTER(MK_data!$2:$17,MK_data!$1:$1=B2))-SUM(FILTER(MK_data!$2:$17,MK_data!$1:$1=B1)))
```

The other is for the Δ # and looks like this.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SUM(N(FILTER(MK_data!$2:$17,MK_data!$1:$1=B3)<>FILTER(MK_data!$2:$17,MK_data!$1:$1=B2)))))
```

Is that what you're going for?  were you looking to have separate columns for Value Added and Value Lost?  That's easy to change, I just wasn't sure.

Comment: Hey Matt, this is really helpful, thank you! If I could, I would give you extra points for the clean solution and presentation haha.

Ideally, I would be able to separate columns for Value Added and Value Lost, but I'll be able to take it from here.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

for starters here is the unpivoted sum logic:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(A1:E1), MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({SIGN(A2:A17)^0-1, 
 IF(A2:E17<>B2:F17, B2:F17-A2:E17, )*1}, 99^99, COLUMNS(A:E))), ROW(A2:A17)^0)})
```

[image: 0]